# Issue with NodeJS async/await - accessing function parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, nodes, puppeteer

I am trying to do some scraping using a library and my code uses Node's 
   async/await pattern.

I have defined a variable 'page' in function named 'sayhi' and I pass the same variable to function ex, I get error while running the code.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function sayhi() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.example.com/'); // 
  ex(page); //FAILS

  var frames2 = await newpage.frames(); // WORKS
}

function ex(newpage){
  var frames = await newpage.frames(); // FAILING
}

sayhi();
```

Comment: `ex()` needs to be made `async`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `await` in a function that isn't an `async` function. Try this instead:

`async function ex(newpage) {`

If you need `frames2` to run only after `ex` is finished completely, you'll also want to `await ex(page);` in `sayhi`.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I did as suggested. Solved my problem.